# Domain and range of constant function

Tags: functions

I found a constant function $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{2-x} = (-1)$$ and here we can see that $f(x)$ is defined for every value of $x$ except 2.
Therefore,$$\mathbb{dom}(f(x)) = \mathbb{R} - \{2\}$$ And for range of $f(x)$ $$ \mathbb{range}(f(x)) = -1$$ Now,  $$f(x) = \frac{x-2}{2-x}=y$$
$$ x = g(y) = \frac{2y+2}{y+1} = 2$$
And $g(y)$ is defined for all values of $y$ except $(-1)$.
Therefore$$\mathbb{dom}(g(y)) = \mathbb{{R}} - \{-1\}$$
And $$ \mathbb{range}(g(y)) = 2$$
Thus we can conclude that range of $g$ is that value which is not in domain of $f$ and range of $f$ is that value which is not in domain of $g$.
So is this correct as I observed this for functions that cancel out and become a constant function.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain that what do you mean with **if a function is not 1-1 and onto**

Comment: It looks like you are solving for the inverse of a function that does not have an inverse, which is why you are getting a strange result.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is all correct.

The point is, I guess, that both $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ have *empty* domain.